Integral of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}$ using the Residue theorem
I'm having some trouble with the following integral:
$$
I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}.
$$
I have chosen a semi-annular contour $\Gamma$ with an inner radius of $\varepsilon$ and outer radius of $R$, and have shown that the integral over these radii vanishes as $\varepsilon\to 0$, $R\to\infty$. There is a simple pole within $\Gamma$ at $z=9i$, hence by the residue theorem
\begin{aligned}
\oint_\Gamma\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx&=\int_{-R}^\varepsilon\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx+\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx\\
&=\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\ln\left(-x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx+\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx\\
&=\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\left(\ln\left(x^3\right)+i\pi\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx+\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx\\
&=2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{\ln\left( x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81},\space x=9i \right).
\end{aligned}
Expanding out $\frac{\left(\ln\left(x^3\right)+i\pi\right)^2}{x^2+81}$, we get
\begin{gather}
2\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx+2\pi i\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)}{x^2+81}dx-\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{\pi^2}{x^2+81}dx\\
=2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{\ln\left( x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81},\space x=9i \right).
\end{gather}
For the residue, we have
\begin{aligned}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{\ln\left( x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81},\space x=9i \right)&=\lim_{x\to 9i}\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{(x-9i)(x+9i)}(x-9i)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 9i}\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x+9i}=\frac{\ln\left(-9^3i\right)^2}{18i}\\
&=\frac{\ln\left(9^3\right)-\pi i\ln\left(9^3\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{18i}.
\end{aligned}
Hence, letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $R\to\infty$ we have
$$
2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx+2\pi i\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)}{x^2+81}dx-\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\pi^2}{x^2+81}dx}_{\pi^3/18}=\pi\frac{\ln\left(9^3\right)^2-\pi i\ln\left(9^3\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{9}.
$$
Comparing the real parts of both sides, we get
\begin{aligned}
2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx-\frac{\pi^3}{18}&=\frac{\pi\ln\left(9^3\right)^2}{9}+\frac{\pi^3}{36}\\
\implies \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx&=\frac{\pi\ln\left(9^3\right)^2}{9}+\frac{\pi^3}{24}.
\end{aligned}
Though according to Wolframalpha, the correct expression is
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^3\right)^2}{x^2+81}dx=\frac{\pi\ln\left(9^3\right)^2}{9}+\frac{\pi^3}{8}.$$
I don't know where I've gone wrong, so any help would be appreciated!

What about the pole at $z=-9i$?
